# How to convert MXD to DWG File

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, mxd, dxf, dwg

I have been trying to export from MXD format to DWG format without much success. I used the Export to CAD conversion tool in GIS 9.3 but it only converts the lines and polygon.. etc to DWG format and NOT the colors and texts that are also included in the original MXD file. Any idea of how I might be able to convert the WHOLE MXD to CAD with all the features included?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, which may not be very far, you can't do that. An mxd is a separate document from the data it contains. Many CAD programs can use shapefiles, although again you wouldn't get symbology. For text, try converting it to annotation and maybe that will export to CAD. Do this on a copy of your data. I'm more used to bringing CAD into Arc than Arc out to CAD.

edit: The reason for this is that symbology, labels, etc., are properties of the mxd, not the data itself, and an mxd is not data. You can export your feature classes to layer files (filename.lyr), which will preserve the symbology, but I have no idea if CAD programs can import those.